# Is $('foo bar') equivalent to $('foo').find('bar')?

Tags: jquery

I'm finding `$('foo bar')` extremely slow in some circumstances. `$('foo').find('bar')` seems to work in all the cases I can think of, and is much quicker. Are they equivalent or am I being daft?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery("foo bar") vs jquery("foo").find("bar")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894418/jqueryfoo-bar-vs-jqueryfoo-findbar)

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Not a dupe. That question is about the first selector working and the second selector not working.

Comment: The answer to that question also answers this question.

Comment: I'm intrigued by "much quicker". I would have expected the opposite in `querySelectorAll` browsers.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Doesn't matter, questions should be closed as dupes based on the question, not the answer.

Comment: @EkoostikMartin [Duplicate Answers are not the same as duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/closing-as-duplicate-when-the-answers-are-duplicates).

Comment: @lonesomeday - extremely basic speed test: http://jsperf.com/find-test-so608 - for me (Safari 7), `.find()` is faster.

Comment: @Joe And for me (Chrome 35) they're essentially identical. I'm astonished at how ill-optimised `qSA` is.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this article outlines why `.find` is faster in certain cases
http://24ways.org/2011/your-jquery-now-with-less-suck/

I guess it all depends how well the selector maps to a native browser selector vs a pseudo selector that has to be interpreted

Comment: Your second sentence is, of course, wholly right, but it's worth pointing out that that article is three years old -- an eternity in terms of the developments in web browsers in recent times.

Comment: @lonesomeday I agree, but to your point.. I was actually putting in code to work with IE 7 and IE 8 as late as today :-)

Comment: It differs between versions of jQuery and browser as well.

Answer (score -4):

$('foo bar') will look for bar and then will mark it selected if it is descendant of foo.

$('foo').find('bar') will select all foo and will now find all descendant bar in the selection